# Auto generated javascript jax-rs client

Tags: java, javascript, rest, jax-rs

I'd like to have something generate for me Javascript service stubs based on JAX-RS annotations.

I found something in [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/AJAX_Client.html) but I cannot make it work when using RESTEasy configured on SpringMVC. It seems it works only if RESTEasy is configured as servlet.

However I'd like to have JS code generated on build time instead runtime.

Do you know any solution that may do sometking like this?

Comment: The RESTEasy implementation is the only one I am aware of, and it has its quirks. Do post back if you find one, its a very interesting topic!

Comment: It seems that Apache CXF has only a JS generator for SOAP enpoints (sic!) but not for REST ones.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has a wizard "RESTful JavaScript Client", inside "Web Services" that generates an html page with all the javascript needed. It could be a good point to start.

You will need a wadl describing your restful webservices. You can try [this](http://tomayac.de/rest-describe/latest/RestDescribe.html) to generate this wadl file.